# How to check or validate for a Enter key

Tags: android

How to check for a enter key on edit text in android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implement OnKeyListener in your Activity and override its onKey() method :

```
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    flag = false;

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
        if (event.getAction() != KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                         flag = false;
        } else if (event.getAction() != KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                         // do your work on Enter key pressed.
                         flag = true;
        }
    }

    return flag;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
            (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
          // Perform action on key press
          Toast.makeText(HelloFormStuff.this, edittext.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

try this

Answer (score 1):

use `onKeyListener` for checking Enter press

for e.g..

```
edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction()!=KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                return false;
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER ){
                            //your necessary codes...
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
```

for more information, check the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have a save button and you want to do the validation when it is clicked?

```
saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String textInput = myEditText.getText().toString();
        // do your validation here
    }
});
```